# Updating has many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.5` where I'm having two models: `Interaction` and `Interaction Summary` in my `Interaction` model I'm having following relationship:

```
public function meetingSummaries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InteractionSummary');
}
```

Now to create the interaction I'm using following in my controller:

```
$data = $request->only('user_id', 'event_type', 'schedule', 'summaries', 'type', 'venue', 'with_client');
$data['schedule'] = Carbon::parse($request->schedule)->addHours(5)->addMinutes(30)->toDateTimeString();
$meeting = [];
$meeting['user_id']= $data['user_id'];
$meeting['schedule'] = $data['schedule'];
$meeting['type'] = $data['type'];
$meeting['with_client'] = $data['with_client'];
$meeting['venue'] = $data['venue'];
$meeting['event_type'] = $data['event_type'];
$interaction = Interaction::create($meeting);
if($data['summaries'])
{
    $container = [];
    foreach($data['summaries'] as $summary)
    {
        $summary = (Object)$summary;
        if($summary->client['label'])
        {
            $container[] = new InteractionSummary([
                'company_id' => $summary->client['label'],
                'nature' => $summary->type,
                'user_id' => $summary->mention['label'],
                'action' => $summary->action,
                'feedback' => $summary->comment
            ]);
            }
        }
    }
    $interaction->meetingSummaries()->saveMany($container);
}
```

But while updating I don't know to overcome this, as in my fields there might be new or old relational data. I'm trying something like this:

```
if($data['summaries'])
{
    $container = [];
    foreach($data['summaries'] as $summary)
    {
        $summary = (Object)$summary;
        if($summary->id)
        {
            $container[] = new InteractionSummary([
                'id' => $summary->id,
                'company_id' => $summary->client['value'],
                'nature' => $summary->type,
                'user_id' => $summary->mention['value'],
                'action' => $summary->action,
                'feedback' => $summary->comment
            ]);
        }
        else {
            $container[] = new InteractionSummary([
                'company_id' => $summary->client['value'],
                'nature' => $summary->type,
                'user_id' => $summary->mention['value'],
                'action' => $summary->action,
                'feedback' => $summary->comment
            ]);
        }
    }
    $interaction->meetingSummaries()->save($container);
}
```

Which is sending me error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in ~\app\Http\Controllers\InteractionsController.php on line 449

If I do:

```
$interaction->meetingSummaries()->saveMany($container);
```

I get repeated new fields.

Guide me how to overcome this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `findOrNew()` method:

```
$summaryItem = InteractionSummary::findOrNew($summary->id);
$summaryItem->fill([
    'company_id' => $summary->client['value'],
    'nature' => $summary->type,
    'user_id' => $summary->mention['value'],
    'action' => $summary->action,
    'feedback' => $summary->comment
]);
```

Comment: If new fields which is not having `summary->id` then? will it throw error?

Comment: @NitishKumar if row with `id = $summary->id` doesn't exist, a new object will be created.

Comment: I'm getting an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '106' in 'field list' (SQL: select `106`, `Idea sharing`, ``, ``, `Documents to be presented` from `interaction_summaries` where `interaction_summaries`.`id` = 247 and `interaction_summaries`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)`

Comment: I'm using `$summary = (Object)$summary;` to change the data to objects, while adding a new summary I'm getting `Undefined property: stdClass::$id` error. Can you  help me in this?

Comment: @NitishKumar looks like you don't need to convert it to an object at all. Just use `$summary['id']` notation.

Comment: I get `Undefined index: id`

Comment: @NitishKumar I mean remove `$summary = (Object)$summary;` and use the `['id']` notation.

Comment: yes I did the same, anyways will sort out this, thanks for your help.